# Объединение строк в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

У меня есть [датафрэйм](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/I4QWaHXyiaFpYA)

Ниже его скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь посчитать сколько времени ID с номером (8690950461832000) находился в каждой зона (признак Идентификатор зоны).
Т.е сделать группировку примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В группировке надо посчитать  нахождение ID в зоне. (это разница признаков "Время последнего взаимодействия" первой регистрации нахождения в первой зоны и первой регистрации в следующей зоне). По последней зоне по идее 0, тк она последняя.

И на выходе что-то вроде такого (Надеюсь время правильно посчитал):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно попробовать так:

```
res = df.groupby([(df["Идентификатор зоны"] != df["Идентификатор зоны"]
             .shift()).cumsum(), "ID", "Идентификатор зоны"], as_index=False)["Время последнего взаимодействия"].first().reset_index(drop=True)

res["Время в зоне"] = res["Время последнего взаимодействия"].diff().shift(-1).fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
```

res:

```
                 ID  Идентификатор зоны Время последнего взаимодействия    Время в зоне
0  8690950461832000                   2             2021-03-17 08:22:17 0 days 00:06:58
1  8690950461832000                   1             2021-03-17 08:29:15 0 days 00:02:34
2  8690950461832000                   2             2021-03-17 08:31:49 0 days 00:57:51
3  8690950461832000                   1             2021-03-17 09:29:40 0 days 00:00:43
4  8690950461832000                   2             2021-03-17 09:30:23 0 days 00:00:00
```